# RoR devise custom sign up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

am using devise with simple_form, can't seem to get a simple sign up working on a view that isn't generated by devise. Any help is appreciated!

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
 = f.input :email
 = f.input :password
 = f.input :password_confirmation
 = f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-blue"
```

Controller:

```
def set_user
@user = params[:id] ? User.find(params[:id]) : User.new
end

def new
end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      redirect_to overview_path, notice: "logged in"
     else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

Also, the params being passed in:

```
user[email]:lol@lol.com
user[password]:123123
user[password_confirmation]:123123
commit:Sign up
```

but @user.password = nil, and it returns an error!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with devise you have encrypted_paasword field in d/b, not password and password_confirmation, those are just virtual attributes.

Comment: yes but you still assign user[password] in your params to pass to devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller do you have something like this? (or is yours attr_accessible?)

```
def post_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password)
end
```

Comment: was biting myself in the butt by not permitting :password :P

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes to see if your path is being changed. That is you would have your own controller and so the path has to be defined something like

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise comes with default views for sign-in/sign-out. In order to override the Devise views, you need to generate them first using:

rails generate devise:views

From there, you can go to app\views\devise\sessions\new and change the standard template. That is the simplest way from my experience.

Comment: Devise creates a template for that as well, but it appears you solved your question.